# Android Market app throwing "a server error has occurred" error message

Tags: google-play-store, 2.2-froyo

I have Samsung I5500 Galaxy 5 running on Android 2.2. I don't know when this error started, but when I open the Market application, it throws the following error:

> A server error has occurred. Retry, or cancel and return to the previous screen.

I have tried a factory reset, but it didn't solve the issue.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Google has ended the support for the Android Market app. Users need to migrate to the Play Store app by installing the compatible version (skip to the last section).

---

#### Background

According to [Android Authority](https://www.androidauthority.com/google-end-android-market-support-781487/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=gplus), Google has ended Android Market support for Android 2.1 Eclair and below:

> On June 30, devices running Android 2.1 Eclair or lower will no longer be able to access, or install other apps from, the Android Market.

In [a different article](https://www.androidauthority.com/android-market-google-play-different-787082/), they also stated an opinion that the Android Market app would no longer be supported on "newer" versions:

> Google also mentioned that it will continue to support “later versions of Android Market for as long as feasible.” Exactly what that means is anyone’s guess, but I think it’s safe to say that the company will eventually end support for Android Market on other versions of its operating system — and probably sooner rather than later.

The Play Store app is supported on Android 2.2 Froyo, and by default, the Android Market app should be automatically updated [on supported devices](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131) when it's opened:

> If you still have the Android Market on your device for whatever reason, it’s probably best if you upgrade it to the newer and much improved Google Play — provided you are running Froyo or newer. As soon as you open the Android Market app, a window will pop up saying that a new version is available for download. Then just follow the directions on your screen, and in a minute or two the Android Market will be replaced by Google Play.

---

#### The issue

However, according to some reports ([1](https://www.androidauthority.com/android-market-google-play-different-787082/#comment-3792350992), [2](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/play/0-wxahDHoVc/-86MxjYvDgAJ)), the Android Market shows an error message "A server error has occurred. Retry, or cancel and return to the previous screen." since at least 8 March 2018, preventing it to be updated to the Play Store app, and thus making it dysfunctional.

---

#### The fix

While the Android Market app cannot update itself, users are still able to install the Play Store app by downloading and installing the APK.

[APKMirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/#variants) listed all variants for the Play Store app, including for Android 2.2 Froyo. The latest version available on there is [4.9.13](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/google-play-store-4-9-13-3-release/google-play-store-4-9-13-android-apk-download/).

> Version: 4.9.13 (80290013)
>   Package: com.android.vending
>   Min: Android 2.2 (Froyo, API 8)